# Add additional logic to the VBA code for additional functionality

Tags: vba, excel

Need to add some additional logic to the code to make it do some more things for me.

So here it is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
If Target.Address = Home.Range("_newCustomer").Address Then
  Set rng = Sheets("Customers").Range(IIf(Range("_newCustomer") = "Company", "Company", "Customer_Name"))
  On Error Resume Next
  i = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("_newCustomer"), rng, 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Home.Range("_paymentDue").Value = IIf(i = 0, "", Sheets("Customers").Range("Customers").Cells(i, 12))
  Home.Range("_invoiceDueDate").Value = IIf(Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value = 0, "", Home.Range("_paymentTermsDay").Value + Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value)
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

so far it works fine, but what I also need from it is when I am changing the value in the range `_invoiceDate`, the range `_invoiceDueDate` should reflect the change, for instance if I am deleting everything from `_invoiceDate` the `_invoiceDueDate` should act accordingly. Also if I am changing anything in the range `_paymentDue`, which is a dropdown list, this change must also change the value of the `_invoiceDueDate` as it is shown in the code above `Home.Range("_invoiceDueDate").Value = IIf(Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value = 0, "", Home.Range("_paymentTermsDay").Value + Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value)`.

Please help

Comment: but as I see it's already reflects: `Home.Range("_invoiceDueDate").Value = IIf(Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value = 0, "", Home.Range("_paymentTermsDay").Value + Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value).` What is actual problem?

Comment: Your are right it does, but only when I change the value in the range _newCustomer, I also need those additional options to change the values too.

Comment: @simoco, the changes made in the range _newCustomer, will assign all default values to the rest of the named ranges used on the worksheet, but as I have mentioned, if someone need to use anything other than the default than they should be able to do it too. At this moment it is not possible with my code, therefore I need to add this functionality to it, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    If Target.Address = Range("_newCustomer").Address Then
      Set rng = Sheets("Customers").Range(IIf(Range("_newCustomer") = "Company", "Company", "Customer_Name"))
      On Error Resume Next
      i = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("_newCustomer"), rng, 0)
      On Error GoTo 0
      Range("_paymentDue").Value = IIf(i = 0, "", Sheets("Customers").Range("Customers").Cells(i, 12))
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("_newCustomer"), Range("_invoiceDate"), Range("_paymentDue"))) Is Nothing Then
          Range("_invoiceDueDate").Value = IIf(CStr(Range("_invoiceDate").Value) = "", "", IIf(CStr(Range("_paymentTermsDay").Value) = "", 0, Range("_paymentTermsDay").Value) + Range("_invoiceDate").Value)
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I can, use just range, and no, the code in your answer did not work in the way I need it to work.

Comment: `the code in your answer did not work in the way I need it to work.` - can you be more specific? what code do right now and what you expect it should do?

Comment: Basically, what should happen is, when you have selected the new customer, all default values from customer DB are assigned to the relevant cells, then if yoiu decide to change the default payment terms from the default to lets say 15 days, than the date in _invoiceDueDate should reflect this change

Comment: what addresses of `the default payment terms `?

Comment: Perfect, works exactly as I need it to work, thanks a lot for this, can you help me with one other thing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49345/discussion-between-simoco-and-alexb)

Comment: Now it works, this is it I guess, how can I translate formula in cell N5 to VBA to avoid using formula on the Worksheet?